# How to escape # in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I need to include a # symbol in an environment variable. For example:
environment:
      - SHARED_KEY=ABC#123

How do I escape the # symbol, so that it is not interpreted as the start of a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any kind of quotes:

```
environment:
  - "SHARED_KEY=ABC#123"
  - 'OR=single quotes {!}'
```